# Can the shape of a potential well be found by pretending quantum particles behave classically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

One example I'm talking about is the potential well of an electron in a hydrogen atom. We solve the Schrödinger equation for the elecron by starting with the potential well of $V\propto-\frac1r$, which is how electric potential behaves in the classical model of electrodynamics.

Comment: The potential well is what it is, regardless of whether the system behaves classically or quantumwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the classical limit, quantum mechanics has to recover the predictions of classical mechanics. So it is certainly a reasonable guess to suppose that, at least to some leading order approximation, the potential appearing in the Schrodinger equation for an electron in a Hydrogen atom is the Coulomb potential. We don't just have to assume this, however; the predictions made by quantum mechanics with the Coulomb potential agree very well with experimental observations of the spectrum of Hydrogen.

It's also reasonable to suppose that at a higher level of precision, the classical Coulomb potential (which is not relativistic and ignores the quantum mechanical spin of the electron as well as the quantum nature of the electromagnetic field) is not sufficient to describe Hydrogen. This is also true. One can compute relativistic and quantum (eg higher order terms in the kinetic energy, spin-orbit and spin-spin coupling, Lamb shift) corrections to the Hamiltonian, and these give rise to small corrections to the energy which agree with more precise measurements of the Hydrogen spectrum.

Comment: So it sounds like the answer is "almost," at least in the case of a hydrogen atom.

Comment: @zucculent I'd say the answer in quantum mechanics is the same as in any other branch of science. You make a guess, drawing on whatever prior knowledge you have to guess well, and then you check your guess with experiment. If it works, you celebrate (until better data comes), and if it doesn't work, you try to refine your guess. In quantum mechanics, a well-established and successful heuristic for guessing is to use the classical limit.